# Cron script to restart apache server doesn't work

Tags: linux, apache, cron

This is the first time I'm using cron. I want to restart the apacher in my server if the amount of available memory goes less than 500 mb. To do so I wrote the following script:

**restart_if_memory_full.sh (in  /var/www/myapp/)**

```
#!/bin/bash

mem=$(free -m | awk '/Mem:/{print $4}')
(( mem <= 500 )) && (sudo service apache2 restart)
```

Then I did it executable by running (`sudo chmod +x restart_if_memory_full.sh`) and added the following line to the cron by (`sudo crontab -e`) (Note I did not use .sh extension as recommended)

```
* * * * * /var/www/myapp/restart_if_memory_full
```

Now, I check the output by (`grep CRON /var/log/syslog`) and see this:

```
Nov 11 11:13:01 mardy2 CRON[31963]: (root) CMD (/var/www/myapp/restart_if_memory_full)
Nov 11 11:13:01 mardy2 CRON[31962]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

However, when I check the memory usage by htop, it doesn't decrease and therefore I realized apache server was not restarted. So, how can I make this script runnable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically answered your question yourself:

> Note I did not use .sh extension as recommended

This is not just an extension, it's part of the filename. So if your script was saved as `/var/www/myapp/restart_if_memory_full.sh` you can't just remove the suffix. Cron won't find that file and will not do anything. Cron even would want to inform you about it by e-mail, but there is no mailserver installed to send an alert:

`(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)`.

So use the full path and name of the script:

```
* * * * * /var/www/myapp/restart_if_memory_full.sh
```

Comment: Hey, thanks alot. I should have at least tried it with extension name as well. I just saw some blogpost recommending not to use extension name. Thanks!